# Borel measurability of a set where convergence occurs

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be a jointly Borel measurable function. I am wondering if the set $$\left\{x\in\mathbb R\,\bigg|\,\lim_{y\to0}F(x,y)=0\right\}$$ is Borel measurable.

The main difficulty is that even though the set $$\left\{x\in\mathbb R\,\bigg|\,\lim_{n\to\infty}F(x,y_n)=0\right\}$$ is Borel measurable for a *given* sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converging to $0$, this must hold for all, *uncountably many*, such sequences. Therefore, taking intersections does not help.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Borel set $A$ in the plane, whose projection on the $x$-axis is not Borel.  (An observation by Souslin.) We use this to build a counterexample.

We may assume our set $A$ is in a square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.  Its projection
$$
p(A) = \{ x \in \mathbb R: \exists y, (x,y) \in A\}
$$
is not Borel.

Build a new set
$$
B = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n
$$
where $A_n$ is the affine image of $A$ in the rectangle $[0,1]\times[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$.  (The image of $A$ under the affine map $(x,y) \mapsto (x,\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{y}{n(n+1)})$.) Then $B$ is a countable union of Borel sets, so $B$ is a Borel set in the plane.  Let $F$ be the indicator of $B$, so that $F(x,y) = 1$ if $(x,y) \in B$ and $F(x,y)=0$ otherwise.  Since $B$ is a Borel set, $F$ is 
a Borel function.  Then
$$
\{x : \lim_{y\to 0} F(x,y) = 0\} = \mathbb R \setminus p(A)
$$
is not a Borel set.

Comment: (+1) Thank you for enlightening the nature of the set $C = \{x : \lim_{y\to 0} F(x,y) = 0\}$. I know nothing about descriptive set theory, but now I can see that $C$ is in general a coanalytic set: $$C = \bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \Bbb{R} \setminus \pi( \{ (x, y) : 0 < |y| < \tfrac{1}{n} \text{ and } |F(x, y)| \geq \tfrac{1}{m} \} ). $$

Comment: @GEdgar The frequency and degree of complications associated with checking Borel measurability never cease to amaze me... Thank you very much.